# I can't receive data, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote the code for receiving and transmitting data.  but when you start the activity, the application crashes.here is the problem line (according to Logcat)

```
String msg=snapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

complete data receiving code with complete information about each object in this activity (except adapter and holder)

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        String msg=snapshot.getValue(String.class);

        messages.add(msg);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        recyclemanwoman.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

data send code

```
private void ValidateAndSaveOnlyInfo() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edit_chat.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Введите текст", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();

        userMap.put("uid", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        userMap.put("text", edit_chat.getText().toString());

        databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);

        edit_chat.setText("");
    }
}
```

i tried to change send HashMap to String

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        String msg= edit_chat.getText().toString();

        if (msg.equals("")){
            return;
        }

        if (msg.length()==MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTMAH){
            return;
        }

        databaseReference.push().setValue(msg);
    }
});
```

but the problematic line is the same.  how can this be fixed?

Comment: are you sure this is js related?

Comment: no but to add a question requires at least one popular tag I wrote java and android but he wrote anyway I saw that JavaScript was more popular and that was the only way I could add

Comment: change it to java

Comment: `wrote the code for receiving and transmitting data.` Receiving from who? Transmitting to what? Please start a post telling what you do.

Comment: getting text, passing to firebase

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and complete stack trace that you copy/paste from the logcat. It'll also be helpful if you include the JSON data that exists at `databaseReference` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.